# How to determine if cAdvisor is installed and what is its version/origin

Tags: kubernetes, containers, cadvisor

We have a number of Kubernetes clusters that we use for our daily work. I am trying to determine:

1. Is `cAdvisor` installed and running?
2. What is its version and origin?

Based on my research, `cAdvisor` appears to originate from Google (https://github.com/google/cadvisor).

I've heard that it's "built-in" to Kubelet, but not sure if that's true. If it is, I suppose it would be very difficult to determine if it's really there and running, never mind where it came from or what version it is. If this not necessarily true, then that might make the job a little easier.

Does anyone have information on how to make this determination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to disable cAdvisor in kubelet.

You can find metrics collect by cAdvisor at kubelet metrics endpoint.

```
kubectl proxy &

curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/nodes/[Nodename]/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
```

For cAdvisor version info, because it's a compiled dependency in kubelet binary, you should dig into [kubernetes source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/go.mod), search for cadvisor, you will find the version.